# How to set sign up with email or phone-number option in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

How to set sign up with email or phone-number option in AWS Cognito?

So I would like to have a simple sign-up. I want users to sign-up with username, email/phone-number, password and repeat password. How can I configure the ability to make it that either email or phone-number is required?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I do not know what methods are available to achieve what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to create the user pool in the console I am at the steps where they are asking for required and custom attributes. How can I require attributes conditionally? Yes I have googled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to require attributes conditionally is to have them as not required in the User Pool settings and define a [Pre sign-up Lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html) function that will verify the presence of at least one of the fields at Sign up, and reject if none is provided (similar to this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-registration-example-3)):

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // Impose a condition that the email or phone_number is provided.
    var userAttributes = event.request.userAttributes;
    if (!userAttributes.email && !userAttributes.phone_number) {
        var error = new Error("Cannot register users without email or phone number");
        // Return error to Amazon Cognito, fail sign up
        callback(error, event);
    }
    // Return to Amazon Cognito, proceed with sign up
    callback(null, event);
};
```

Comment: Does AWS cognito use AWS lambda under the hood? Thus why we can use lambda trigger to manage how it works? I am new to AWS lambda and cognito so I am trying to understand how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, AWS Cognito allows making use of AWS lambda functions at several steps of the user pool workflow in order to customize its behavior. You can learn which events and how to configure them [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html).